# How can I specify what the default child route is?

Tags: nuxt.js

They describe here

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-routes

That you can use the _id.vue to be the initial child page. But I would like to have a concrete page as my child page. Is that possible?

So this is working currently

```
pages/
--| posts/
-----| _id.vue
--| posts.vue
```

By using

```
<nuxt-child />
```

in posts.vue. But I would like this

```
pages/
--| posts/
-----| post1.vue
--| posts.vue
```

Where post1 would be my initial child.

Comment: you could put `index.vue` together with `_id.vue` into posts. With `/posts` you land on index.vue and with `/posts/someId` on `_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure should be like this:

```
pages/
--| posts/
-----| post1.vue
-----| index.vue
```

index.vue should route like /posts